# How to disable duplicated values options when adding new option of an attribute magento 2

Tags: magento2, delete, attribute-options

I have set the attribute color as unque value but still can add same value and i have tried with an event catalog_entity_attribute_save_before but now he delete all the label and values please any help here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_entity_attribute_save_before">
        <observer name="color_swatches" instance="Description\Set\Observer\ChangeColorOptions" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and here is my helper that i called then in the observer :

```
<?php

namespace Description\Set\Helper;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_resource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    )
    {
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    }

    public function checkColorExists($color)
    {
        $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);

        $result = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT  DISTINCT value FROM `eav_attribute_option_value` WHERE option_id IN (SELECT option_id FROM `eav_attribute_option` WHERE `attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'color'))");
        foreach ($result as &$value) {
            $value = $value['value'];
        }
        if (!in_array($color, $result)) {

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the observer:

```
<?php

namespace Description\Set\Observer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\AttributeFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;




class ChangeColorOptions implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $dataHelper;
    protected $_productAttributeRepository;
    protected $eavSetupFactory;
    protected $setup;
    protected $_resource;
    protected $messageManager;



    public function __construct(

        \Description\Set\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource


    )
    {

        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        $this->_productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->setup = $setup;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;


    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)

    {


        //$options = $this->_productAttributeRepository->get('color')->getOptions();


        $attributeCode = 'color';
        $attributeId = 93;
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $attributeModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute')->load($attributeId);
        $options = $attributeModel->getSource()->getAllOptions(); //get all options
        $resource = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $myTable = $this->_resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_option_value');

        foreach ($options as $value) {


            $result = $this->dataHelper->checkColorExists($value['label']);

            if (!$result) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__("This color exists yet."));
                $test = $value['value'];
                $connection->delete($myTable,['option_id = ?' => $test]);




            }


        }



    }
}
```

now i even the new color does not exist in the options it show me error and delete all the values any idea please and thanks in advance